# How to solve PyTorch UnicodeEncodeError error when using torch.from_numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I am using PyTorch with python3.
I tried the following while in ipdb mode:

```
regions = np.zeros([107,4], dtype='uint8')
torch.from_numpy(regions)
```

This prints the tensor. 
However when trying:

```
regions = np.zeros([107,107,4], dtype='uint8')
torch.from_numpy(regions)
```

I get the following error:

```
*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u22ee' in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm am using:

```
numpy==1.11.3
torch==0.2.0.post4
torchvision==0.1.9
```

and python3.5.3

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes?

Comment: I find several solutions and all says the same, try to find what file are you importing on your script that use *with open(filename) as* and change it for *with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as* . That worked for me. Check these solutions:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750843/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919076/python-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character-maps-to-undefi,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648154/read-lines-of-a-textfile-and-getting-charmap-decode-error

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to run both versions of your code with no issues in a jupyter notebook. I'm gonna say that this kind of Unicode codec error is not due to `.from_numpy()`

I'm running Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)

```
numpy==1.13.0
torch==0.1.12.post2
torchvision==0.1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

From the website `http://pytorch.org/` they say:

> Please ensure that you are on the latest pip and numpy packages.

I was not able to reproduce your errors with recent versions of numpy and pytorch. I think `pip install -U numpy` might solve the problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem trying https://github.com/jojonki/BiDAF I did what you suggest and I'm still having the same problem.